# Auto color of tabs in Firefox based on URL/domain?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, browser-tabs

I need to have open three URLs that are the same on three different servers. It becomes bit hard to quickly select the tab I need to go to in quick manner.

To have the same color or same color scheme for the same server would be a solution. Can I do that somehow automatically base on URL&domain in Firefox 8.x?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[FlagTab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flagtab/) seems to have what you need.

> - Persistently Mark Tabs That Match a Certain URL/Regex
>
> Persistent URLs are URLs that you want to always color with a certain
>   label. The Mozilla Add-ons url has already been defined and will
>   always color tabs red (until you change or delete it of course ;).
>   Valid inputs for the URL text box can be flat URLs or regex strings.
>   Once a URL has been set, select the label you want to color it, and
>   hit OK. FlagTab will apply the Persistent URL label OVER the previous
>   label, that way once you navigate away from the Persistent URL the
>   color will be restored to its previous state. Use the "x" button to
>   remove a label and the "+ Add Color" to add a new label.

Comment: Looks good, not available for current version of ff though...

Comment: FlagTab doesn't seem to exist anymore :(

Answer (score 1):

Came across another add-on [ColorTabs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/colortabs/) recently, which was really quick to get working. Only drawback is that if you have multiple windows, the color of the window/tab that is in focus also applies to the window that's not in focus.

Bit of an issue if you've got 2 tabs on each screen with prod and dev open simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

I use [colorfultabs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/colorfultabs/) for this.

You do have to set a default match-all rule with a gray color to prevent if from coloring every tab, but from then on it works fine.  I use it to discern between dev, staging and production.

Comment: This is just my use case. But I cannot figure out how to configure the rules. In the add-ons section of Firefox, the addon offers me only some basic input fields to configure colors in general. Do you have any pointers? I am using FF 69. Seems like the FF interface changed a lot.